# How to wait for getDownloadURL to finish in my mapping function before updating my object array in react state?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
getImages() {
  const entries_copy = this.state.entries;
  entries_copy.map(entry => {
    storage.refFromURL(entry.sign_in_photo).getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        entry["inPhotoURL"] = url;
        storage.refFromURL(entry.sign_out_photo).getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          entry["outPhotoURL"] = url;
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle any errors
      });
  });

  this.setState({entries: entries_copy});
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the download url for images and store them in my entry object inside my entries object array but the problem I'm facing right now is that the setState is called before the urls are retrieved and I have no idea how to wait for it to complete before setting the state. I have searched for similar problems but most of them are solved by executing it inside then() but for mine, I can't execute it inside then() because I have to wait for all the entries to be updated. I have only recently started using React for this project so I'm sorry if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the code in asynchronous.
You should call setState inside the .then() function.
I would recommend you to read about Promises in Javascript. They are an important aspect of the language to master.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @TomSlutsky, note that you need to correctly [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) your promises and you should not forget to "always return results, otherwise callbacks won't catch the result of a previous promise".

So you need to do as follows:

```
storage.refFromURL(entry.sign_in_photo).getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        entry["inPhotoURL"] = url;
        return storage.refFromURL(entry.sign_out_photo).getDownloadURL()
      })
      .then((url) => {
          entry["outPhotoURL"] = url;
          this.setState(...);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          // Handle any errors
      });
```

Note also how the `catch()` method is called at the end of the chain, see the doc for more details (and possible other options).